# Url redirection issue in magento

Tags: url-rewrite

Recently I have created a site but I have some issues related to redirections for this http://www.klikgenie.com/women-44/designer-handbags.html

But when I click on the products of this category it is redirecting me 
http://www.klikgenie.com/catalog/product/view/id/12030/category/172/

And also urls of product page from this category was not created properly.
Please let me know what I need to do?

Comment: perform reindexing

Comment: I did that but nothing is happened  :(

Comment: I just tried it and it works for me, I'm getting properly redirected to an URL with the product URL key.
Sounds like reindexing issue + cache refresh to me.

Comment: I reindexed it nothing happened,is there any another solution for this? Can I import again those 30 products which has a redirection issue?

Comment: Please check your .htacess file in root folder, inside the file find  "#RewriteBase" and give your folder name in front of "#RewriteBase like "#RewriteBase /your foldername/  or on server keep it blank , also clear the cache if it is enable and also check the proper re-index.

Answer (score 0):

## First

- Go to Catalog/URL Rewrite Management
- search for catalog/product/view/id/12030/category/172/ in the Target Path search box.
- Open the result you find and do the following.
- change the redirect dropdown to Permanent
- Save it

## And then

- Add url Rewrite using the button at the right corner
- select Custom from the drop down in the next screen
- fill the form fields as

  - give any unique id to id path
  - put catalog/product/view/id/12030/category/172/  for the request path
  - put women-44/designer-handbags.html for target path
  - change the redirect dropdown to Permanent
- Save

Now When you go to http://www.klikgenie.com/women-44/designer-handbags.html you should be able to see your webpage just like http://www.klikgenie.com/catalog/product/view/id/12030/category/172/

Hope this helps.